# Partitioning Enterprise CAL Users from Standard CAL Users

Tags: cal

From within a SharePoint farm how can users be partitioned so as to prevent Standard CAL users from Accessing Enterprise Features?  Can this be done via simply enabling/disabling Enterprise Features by Web Application, audiences or does this require some other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 and 2016, you can use the User Licensing enforcement via PowerShell. This includes the cmdlets `New-SPUserLicenseMapping`, `Add-SPUserLicenseMapping`, and `Enable-SPUserLicenseMapping`. More information can be found on TechNet at [Configure licensing in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219627.aspx).